# Get External SD Card path using getExternalFilesDirs

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I am trying to develop an app which needs read access from external storage AND external mounted sdcards(if any). However, it seems that before API 21 there was no official API to access external sdcard. Starting from API 21 there is the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action. But I need to support API 19 in my app. Browsing through SO, it seems that most of the processes to find sdcards are mostly heuristics. One of the ideas I got is to use `getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1].getAbsolutePath()`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) sayes:

> Returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all
>   shared/external storage devices where the application can place
>   persistent files it owns. These files are internal to the application,
>   and not typically visible to the user as media.

In my mobile the path returned is:

`/storage/9057-287B/Android/data/com.tahsinalsayeed.codeviewer/files`

Now my idea is to remove starting from `Android` till the end of the path. The rest is my external SDCard path. In this case it is `/storage/9057-287B`. I would like to ask whether this method can be used to get external SDcard or not and in which cases it is likely to fail. One fail case is, this method will not return USB Flash drives as mentioned in the documentation. But mounted sdcards should be available.

**Summary: Can I retrieve external SDCard path using `getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1].getAbsolutePath()`? In which cases it is likely to fail?**

Comment: Yes of course this is fine. I do it all the time. You should of course check if the second element [1] is there and not `null`. The method will also often return usb drives (as [2] or [1] if no card inserted) depending on device model.

Comment: But as you cannot write on the whole sd card trying to find its root path often is of little use. Only for reading suited.